# Count Occurrence of a Character in a String on Multiple Rows Sorted by Keyword [vba]

Tags: vba, excel

VBA newbie. Finally encountered an Excel problem I could not address with formulas. Here is my sample data:

```
-----------------------
|   |   A     |  B*   |
-----------------------
| 1 |  Text1  |  3001 |
-----------------------
| 2 |  Text2  |  0231 |
-----------------------
| 3 |  Text1  |  1003 |
-----------------------
| 4 |  Text3  |  0012 |
-----------------------
```

I would like to achieve f(A1:A4, "Text1", B1:B4, "3") = 2.

i.e. I want to count the cumulative occurrence of the character "3" in column B for every row that contains "Text1". Please note that the cells in column B are of type text vs int. If there is a way to achieve this without vba, I would welcome that too.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Function CountCharInStr(FilterStr As String, FilterRange As Range, SearchStr As String,    StrRange As Range) As Integer

    Dim Idx As Integer, IsFound As Boolean
    CountCharInStr = 0
    IsFound = False

    For Idx = 1 To FilterRange.Rows.Count
        IsFound = True
        If FilterRange(Idx) <> FilterStr Then
            IsFound = False
            Exit For
        End If

        If IsFound Then
            CountCharInStr = Len(StrRange(Idx)) - Len(Replace(StrRange(Idx), SearchStr, "")) + CountCharInStr
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Idx

End Function
```

The function currently returns 0, the initial value, instead of 2. Would also like to know if there is a simple way to step through a user defined function for debugging purposes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this directly on the worksheet:

```
     =SUM(IF(A1:A4="Text1",LEN(B1:B4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B4,"3","")),0))
```

Note that this is an **array formula**: you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter (in the Formula Bar) instead of just Enter when editing.

Always better to avoid VBA if possible.

Let me know if you need any explanation on how it works.